# IOS Enterprise Distribution Through OTA with app installation restricted

Tags: ios, manifest, enterprise, ota

We have an iOS enterprise app that we distribute via OTA. All the devices has app installation settings restricted. OTA was working before iOS 10. And, suddenly it stops working from iOS 10 unless we disable app installation restriction.

Is there a way to disable app installation on iOS devices but would still allow enterprise app installation via OTA.

Comment: Have you found solution? We are facing exactly the same issue. Please share with me you have any any idea about

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get any good information from Apple. We already submitted bug report but so far they are not answering my questions. They just asked for the log. I'll post any updates here.